# Bijection between compact space  and maximal ideals of real-valued functions on K

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, solution-verification

I know this question has been asked before, because as I was gonna ask it. A similar question popped up. I just have different question regarding the details of the proof. I am currently studying Aluffi and this question popped up.

Let K be a compact topological space, and let R be the ring of continuous real-valued functions on K, with addition and multiplication defined pointwise.

1. For $p \in K$, let $M_p = \{f \in R | f(p) = 0\}$. Prove that $M_p$ is a maximal ideal in $R$.
2. Prove that if $f_1, \dots, f_r \in R$ have no common zeros, then the ideal generated by $f_1, \dots, f_r$ (let's call it $(f_1, \dots, f_r)$) is equal to $R$. (Hint: Consider $f_1^2 + \cdots + f_r^2$)
3. Prove that ever maximal ideal $M$ in $R$ is of the form $M_p$ for some $p \in K$. (Hint: you will use compactness of $K$ and part 2)

Conclude that $p \rightarrow M_p$ defines a bijection from K to the set of maximal ideals of R.

For part (1).

It is clear that $M_p$ is an ideal. Assume that $[f] \neq [0]$ in the ring $R / M_p$. It follows $f(p) \neq 0$. We know there exists neighbourhood $U$ such that $f(x) \neq 0 \ \forall x \in U$. First question how do we know that the following function is continuous

$g : K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $ x \mapsto \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{f(x)} x \in U \\
      0 \ otherwise
   \end{cases}
$

It is obvious that $[fg] = [1]$. Part (2) is obvious to me because we can consider $f_1^2 + \ldots + f_r^2 > 0$. It follows that $\frac{1}{f_1^2 + \ldots + f_r^2} > 0$. Hence $(f_1,\ldots,f_r) = (1)$. For part (3). Assume that J is maximal and $J$ isn't equal to $M_p$ for any $M_p$. Therefore for each $p \in K$ there exists $f_j \in J$ such that $f_j(p) \neq 0$. It follows there exists neighbourhoods $U_j$ such that $f_j(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in U_j$. By compactness there exists $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ such that $f_j(x) \neq 0$ for $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$. It follows that $f_1 + \ldots f_m \in J$ such that is a unit which is a contradiction. Does anyone see any problem with my solution to part (3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no reason for that $g$ to be continuous. Imagine that $K = [0, 1]$, $f(x) = x$, and $U = (1/4, 3/4)$. Then the extension by $0$ of $1/f$ is definitely not continuous. When you're showing that $R/M_p$ is a field you need to find an inverse to the coset $f + M_p$, not a (local) inverse of $f$. Here's a clean approach. Let $\phi_p: R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be $\phi_p(f) = f(p)$. This map is onto, taking for instance the various constant maps. It's also a ring homomorphism. Furthermore, its kernel is the very definition of $M_p$. Thus, by the first isomorphism theorem, $R/M_p \cong \mathbb R$ via $f + M_p \mapsto f(p)$. Thus, $M_p$ is maximal. This proof essentially says that a coset $f + M_p$ is determined purely by the value of $f(p)$.
2. This is fully correct.
3. Your proof is basically correct, but I dislike the notation $f_j$ for the $f_j \in J - M_p$. What is $j$ supposed to be? I think a much better notation is to let $f_p \in J - M_p$. Then let $p \in U_p$ be a neighborhood such that $f_p \neq 0$ on $U_p$. Then you can apply compactness to get an open cover $U_{p_1} \cup \dots \cup U_{p_m}$ and the functions $f_{p_1}, \dots, f_{p_m}$ therefore vanish nowhere. So by part 2, $R = (f_{p_1}, \dots, f_{p_m}) \subseteq J \subseteq R$. This is really just a stylistic change, but I think it makes it much clearer what is happening.

Comment: Yes, your part (3) is very clear. Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!